# Pull 3 emails from DB and assign them each to 3 different variables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page that sends an email to 3 email recipients. The email addresses are currently hard coded. I want to change it so that I don't need to edit the code to change the email addresses (the emails would need to be change about every 2 years). How I want to  do this is by pulling the emails from the DB and assigning them each to its own variable. In the DB, I have two columns. A "userId" column and a "email" column. I inserted three different  users into the DB. When I run the page, it displays the third email in the DB 3 times rather than the 3 different emails. Do I need to put this in different for loops? What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

**Note:** My email code is currently $to="someone@somewhere.edu"; I want to do away from having to change the emails in the code itself and I prefer to have this done through a variable. So that that the emails in the DB would need to be changed rather than the code having to be edited.

```
$query = "SELECT email FROM timeSheetEmails WHERE userId='1'";
$query = "SELECT email FROM timeSheetEmails WHERE userId='2'";
$query = "SELECT email FROM timeSheetEmails WHERE userId='3'";
    foreach ($conn->query($query) as $row) {
    $emailOne = $row['email'];
    $emailTwo = $row['email'];
    $emailThree = $row['email'];
echo $emailOne . "<br>";
echo $emailTwo . "<br>";
echo $emailThree;
}​
```

Comment: Why not just do one query and select both the userId and the email? `SELECT userId, email from timeSheetEmails WhERE userId in('1','2','3')`

Comment: Is the only purpose of the dB to store these emails?  Sounds like all you actually need is a config file.

Comment: `SELECT email FROM timeSheetEmails WHERE userId IN('1','2','3') ORDER BY userId` should do the job of 3 queries

Comment: Hint: `$query .= "` (you're overwriting the first 2), but that won't fix your code. Use multiple clauses instead and in one query. You can also use the others' comments above.

Comment: @Coda17 yes, the purpose of the DB is to only store the emails. Because in another part of the page I have a section where I send emails. I want to send these emails to 2 of the emails and .CC the third email. My email code is currently $to="someone@somewhere.edu"; I want to do away from having to change the emails in the code itself and I prefer to have this done through a variable. So that that the emails in the DB would need to be changed rather than the code having to be edited.

Comment: @user3666355 A whole dB for 3 fields is massive overkill.  Just use keep a config file with a to list and a cc list.  When you want to change the emails, you only have to change the file and not the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT email FROM timeSheetEmails WHERE userId='1'";
$query = "SELECT email FROM timeSheetEmails WHERE userId='2'";
$query = "SELECT email FROM timeSheetEmails WHERE userId='3'";
```

Here is the problem. You are running only one query, the last one. Why don't you do get all emails and then display them?

```
$query = "SELECT email FROM timeSheetEmails"; 
foreach($conn->query($query) as $row){
    echo $row['email'].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: I tried 3 different queries before, but I did it with 3 loops for each query (which was wrong). For your question, I want to assign each email to its own variable. Your example is part of what I want - all 3 emails are displayed on the page now. Now I want all the emails to be assigned to 3 different variables. Because I have emailing code somewhere else in my page. I want to send the emails to 2 people and Cc: the third email address. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Thanks. From your example, I realized I made a few small mistakes before. Updated code that is working how I want it to:

$query1 = "SELECT email FROM timeSheetEmails WHERE userId='1'";
foreach($conn->query($query1) as $row){
 $emailOne = $row['email'].'<br>';
 echo $emailOne;
}
$query2 = "SELECT email FROM timeSheetEmails WHERE userId='2'";
foreach($conn->query($query2) as $row){
 $emailTwo = $row['email'].'<br>';
 echo $emailTwo;
}
$query3 = "SELECT email FROM timeSheetEmails WHERE userId='3'";
foreach($conn->query($query3) as $row){
 $emailThree = $row['email'].'<br>';
 echo $emailThree;
}

Answer (score 0):

if you need each need to be their own query. you msut parse each result separetely

```
for($I = 1; $I < 4; $I++)
{
    $query = "SELECT email FROM timeSheetEmails WHERE userId='$I'";
    foreach ($conn->query($query) as $row) {
    $email = $row['email'];
    echo $email. "<br>";
    }​
}
```

Otherwise you can do

```
$query = "SELECT email FROM timeSheetEmails WHERE userId In ('1', '2', '3')";
foreach ($conn->query($query) as $row) {
    $email = $row['email'];
    echo $email. "<br>";
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

You are lopping only through the last query, you should use:

```
 $query = "SELECT email FROM timeSheetEmails WHERE userId='1' OR userId='2' OR userId='2'";
 foreach ($conn->query($query) as $row) {
      $emails[] = $row['email'];
  }

  list($emailOne,$emailTwo,$emailThree)=$emails;
```